# How are arrays implemented in java?

Tags: java, arrays, constants

Arrays are implemented as objects in java right? If so, where could I look at the source code for the array class. I am wondering if the length variable in arrays is defined as a constant and if so why it isn't in all capital letters LENGTH to make the code more understandable.

Comment: If it was a constant (as in a static final field), all arrays would have to have the same size (or arrays of different sizes would have to have different types (which would further imply that an array's size would have to be known at compile-time)).

Comment: From what I am understanding from Yishai's answer below is that the array is dynamically created when it is defined.

Comment: sepp2k's point is that there is no one global length field. Generally we think of upper case variables as public static and final. Here length is public and final, but not static, and it's value is different per object instance, although it never changes.

Comment: Useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965458/source-code-for-java-array?rq=1

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Although arrays are Objects in the sense that they inherit java.lang.Object, the classes are created dynamically as a special feature of the language. They are not defined in source code.

Consider this array:

```
MySpecialCustomObject[] array;
```

There is no such source code for that. You have created it in code dynamically.

The reason why length is in lower case and a field is really about the fact that the later Java coding standards didn't exist at the time this was developed. If an array was being developed today, it would probably be a method: getLength().

Length is a final field defined at object construction, it isn't a constant, so some coding standards would not want that to be in upper case. However in general in Java today everything is generally either done as a constant in upper case or marked private with a public getter method, even if it is final.

Comment: what is the general outline for an array class to be generated?

Comment: @sn3twork, Basically array has all of the methods of object, plus a public final length variable and it has a public clone method, implements Cloneable and Serializable (but I assume for legacy reasons not Iterable). Details are in the JLS: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/arrays.doc.html

Comment: thanks for the link http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/arrays.doc.html#11358  I found where it talks about defining arrays using arrays initializers and creation expressions

Comment: Good answer. Even an array of primitives are `Objects`.

Comment: The above link no longer contains the specified information. The updated link is https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.3

Answer (score 4):

For every Array we declare, corresponding classes are there in Java but it's not available to us.You can see the classes by using getClass().getName()

```
    int[] arr=new int[10];
    System.out.println(arr.getClass().getName());
```

Output : **[I**

where "**[**" represents one dimension array and "**I**" represents Integer.
Similarly, we can have

```
    [F for one-dimensional float arrays
    [Z for one-dimensional boolean arrays
    [J for one-dimensional long arrays
    [[I for two-dimensional int arrays
```

and so on.

Answer (score -1):

Implementing array in Java requires access to memory location or do pointer arithmetic. As Java does not let you to allocate memory, it does the Arrays implementation for you. Java language provides that implementation.

Comment: It's not a black box: the source code is available.

Answer (score -3):

We can say that An array is a container that holds a fixed length of data of single data type.
eg.

```
int[] MyArray = new int[101]; // allocates memory for 101 integers, Range from 0 to 100.
```

and for multidimensional

```
String[][] names = {{"FirstName", "LastName"},{"Kaji", "Islam"},...};
```

and for character array

```
char[] ch={'a','b'....};
```