# Where can I find the source code for Java arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

Where can I find the source code for java arrays?

Example:

```
double[] arr=new double[20];
```

All array's with any dimension implements `Cloneable` and Serializable` interface. I searched the source code but couldn't find the code for this.

Comment: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/2d585507a41b/src/share/back/ArrayTypeImpl.c

Comment: @Raúl Irrelevant. That's from the JDWPA, not the JVM.

Answer (score 15):

Have a look at [this](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t668320-source-code-for-array-implementation-in-java.html) for an explanation. But basically the array type is built-in to the jvm and you need to analyze the source code for the jvm you are running in order to truly know how it works.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the [javadocs for java.util.Arrays](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) and here is the [implementation of java.util.Arrays in openjdk](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/back/ArrayTypeImpl.c). Google Code search is a good way to go about it.

**UPDATE 1:** Link updated. Posted the wrong link.

**UPDATE 2:** As pointed out by [thilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14955/thilo), the jvm implementation of Array is [here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#TTY8xLpnKOE/src/share/back/ArrayTypeImpl.c&q=array%20package:%22http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/hotspot/jdk%22)

Comment: I think he's asking about the infrastructure that allows you actually create arrays.  `java.util.Array` is just a utility class.

Comment: Note that this is the source for the Arrays utility class (not the native array data type).

Comment: Google code search is good though, maybe here: http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#TTY8xLpnKOE/src/share/back/ArrayTypeImpl.c&q=array%20package:%22http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/hotspot/jdk%22

Comment: I have updated my answer but, @thilo deserves the acceptance of the answer :)

Comment: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/2d585507a41b/src/share/back/ArrayTypeImpl.c

Comment: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/back/ArrayTypeImpl.c

Comment: These links are for the Java Platform Debugger Architecture. They are not the implementation of array objects in the JVM. Neither is `java.util.Arrays`.