# Is there a .java source file for arrays in the JDK?

Tags: arrays, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Source code for java array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965458/source-code-for-java-array)

There is a [Java source file for `java.lang.Object`](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#ND67gFy8cpo/src/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java&q=open%20jdk&d=0) in the OpenJDK, which surprised me a bit, but I thought it was pretty interesting.

That got me wondering whether there is a source file for arrays (which after all are types of `Object`). Or is their behaviour hard-wired into the JVM somehow?

If such a thing existed, I would expect a lot of the methods to be `native` as I'm not sure how you could make it without being completely self-referential. But I'm curious as to whether it even exists.

Comment: array is a language concept wile Object is a defined class.

Comment: @Bala R, so you are saying that `int a = new int[3]; Class c = a.getClass();` doesn't work?  clearly you can. an array is certainly controlled by a java class.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy I may have not explained well but what I was trying to say was that Object is an entity that is defined in "java" and is used by other "java" classes while array is a language concept and it's built into jvm and you are not going to be able to find "java" code that define array (and from the link below I see it's in C) but I didn't notice the OP is looking any code not just java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Where can I find the source code for Java arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965458/source-code-for-java-array)

The poster also linked to [this](https://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#TTY8xLpnKOE/src/share/back/ArrayTypeImpl.c&q=array%20package%3a%22http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/hotspot/jdk%22) for OpenJDK