# Where is the source code for array objects

Tags: java, arrays, primitive

We can declare arrays of primitives in java.
eg: int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4};

then we can use a.length etc.

But where is the source code for such an object ?

Where is the docjar which defines a value length ?

Is there something happening under the scene ?

Comment: How does an obvious duplicate get 7 upvotes. SO is surely broken. (The original question got just 1 upvote!)

Comment: It's JVM magic. You're not going to find a `.java` file; you'll need to look at the JVM implementation.

Comment: @SLaks : read my comment again.

Comment: Check this link out. You can use google code search as well.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3965487/2579139

Comment: @shalin94: Those links are both dead.  http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/2d585507a41b/src/share/back/ArrayTypeImpl.c

Comment: @MitchWheat Sadly, you can almost wave at the shark directly below at this point :(

Comment: @MitchWheat American idiom; "Jumping the Shark" - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumping_the_shark - was applying it to the "SO is surely broken" portion of your comment.

Comment: @MitchWheat: the original question was posted 3 years ago, a lot less people were visiting here at that point. A lot of new users have arrived in the past few years and will see this question for the first time.

Comment: @Jeroen Vannevel: what they can't use a search engine?

Comment: @MitchWheat: I'm not saying they're right, I'm merely saying that this is the likely cause of this question getting upvotes and the original so few.

Comment: @ALL - my apologies.. and thanks for all for bothering to still care for this duplicate. Next time i ensure prudence.