# What exactly is a Java array? Is it an object? Is it a primitive?

Tags: java, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are arrays implemented in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267790/how-are-arrays-implemented-in-java)
>   [Why isn’t there a java.lang.Array class? If a java array is an Object, shouldn’t it extend Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546500/why-isnt-there-a-java-lang-array-class-if-a-java-array-is-an-object-shouldnt)

I was recently thinking about Java arrays and I was wondering what exactly are they?

**Are they objects?**

- You can call toString() on them (even though it only gives you the
  memory address)
- The following line compiles `Object a = new int[5]`;

**However, are they really objects?**

- You create a new array by `new int[5]`...this is like no constructor
  I've ever seen.  One would think it would be `new Array<Integer>(5)` or something of the sort
- If you look through the Java API you won't find an `array`
  class...You'll find `Array` but this isn't truely an array

**And what's up with it's iterable properties**

- You can go through an array in a for each loop, but there is no `iterator` method of array that I can find

I think array is *just some special exception* built directly into the Java language; however, this also poses the question: why are arrays given special treatment? (Why isn't there an Array API? Why is there a different type of constructor?)

Any clarification regarding the true nature of arrays would be appreciated.

P.S. I have a few years experience in Java, so I know how to use arrays and what they do, I'm just asking how exactly they are implemented and why?

Comment: strikes me as a function of Java development early on-- I've heard that a lot of the functions/objects we know and love were basically developed by interns as summer projects. Which is why we have `.length`, `.length()` and `.size()`

Comment: @colleen - got any proof?

Comment: None at all. Which is why I said "I've heard". That was just something my Software Engineering teacher said.

Comment: They're object-like. int[n] is syntatic sugar, like `String s = "ohai";` AFAIK it was implemented like that so it looked like C/C++, and a lot of that stuff was implemented before Java was standardized (e.g., Java APIs don't follow JavaBean conventions, camelCasing wasn't always consistent, etc.)

Comment: Responding to the third part: arrays don't implement `Iterable` - the for each syntax on arrays only looks the same but is really just a separate language feature.

Comment: @DaveNewton They are objects. JLS chapter 10. int[n] is syntax, and has nothing to do with Strings.

Comment: @EJP `int[n]` is syntax, so is `"foo"`: String literals are syntactic sugar that create string objects. IMO arrays behave as chimeras, half-way between primitives and objects. See the c2wiki page for a long-winded discussion.

Comment: @DaveNewton I agree that String literals are indeed syntactic sugar, and I didn't say otherwise. I disagree that `int[n]` is, and you now seem to be agreeing with me. Re objects, your opinion is your opinion but what it says in the JLS #10 is fact. I don't know what c2wiki is, or where it is, but I am a compiler writer, and I'm not much interested in third party discussions unless they are informed.

Comment: @EJP Not sure what being a compiler writer has to do with anything. I'd venture that in general, c2wiki participants are among the better-informed. The JLS can say whatever it wants-and I agree that arrays are objects-butt they do not *behave* as other objects in the JVM, and as a compiler writer, that should be important to you. YMMV.