# How are arrays created (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

I know that an object is a class instance or an array.

Meaning that when creating an array, an instance of a real class is not created (the classes are created dynamically and are not defined in the source code).

According to the JLS https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.8

> Every array has an associated Class object, shared with all other arrays with the same component type.
>
> Although **an array type is not a class**, the Class object of every array
> acts as if:
>
> - The direct superclass of every array type is Object.
> - Every array type implements the interfaces Cloneable and
>   java.io.Serializable.

Is the Class object associated with the dynamically created class?

Why does the Class object allow arrays to inherit java.lang.Object?

**EDIT:**

To clarify my question.

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/2267807/11306652

> "arrays are Objects in the sense that they inherit java.lang.Object,
> the classes are created dynamically as a special feature of the
> language. They are not defined in source code."

Furthermore,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10674614/11306652

> "[I" is the name of the class which we would call, in English, "array of
> int". The class is a "full citizenship" Java class, which responds to
> all the methods of Object. The only difference is that the new syntax
> is different and it doesn't support the newInstance() method of Class.
>
> The classes "[I", "[C", et al, are "pre-defined" in the JVM -- there
> are no .class files corresponding to them. Java also will implicitly
> create, on the fly,"

Is my understanding correct that when arrays are created, the JVM dynamically creates an "array class" (with Object as a superclass) that defines the array object? Additionally there is a Class object associated with the dynamically created "array class".

Comment: *an instance of a real class is not created (the classes are created dynamically and are not defined in the source code)*  This seems confused.  The truth is simply that an array of something, like int, boolean, float, etc., is not an object of any class.  There are no "dynamically created classes" involved.  Nevertheless, it is convenient for there to be a Class object ("Class", not "class") because Class objects hold useful information about a type.  That the Class says the array inherits from Object does not make it true.

Comment: @another-dave i was unaware that was incorrect, i got that info from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267790/how-are-arrays-implemented-in-java#comment47279973_2267790 see top answer.

Comment: That answer is not appropriate. Consider "There is no such source code for that. You have created it in code dynamically". What is the declaration for ```MySpecialObject[] array``` if not source code?  I suspect the writer is confusing "the class of the array" (there isn't one, an array is not an object of any class) and "the Class object for the array type"  (the [class Class<T>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) holds data about the type T).

Comment: The short answer:  *"Why does the Class object allow arrays to inherit java.lang.Object??"* - Because, actually, in the context of the complete Java language design ... it makes sense.

Comment: The 2nd short answer: *"Is the Class object associated with the dynamically created class?"* - You can get a `Class` object for every object, including objects whose class was dynamically created.  (And arrays ... because arrays are objects.)

Comment: @StephenC another-dave states that no dynamically created classes are involved?

Comment: That is mostly true.  Array types are *typically* not created dynamically, but they could be if you create array objects via reflection.  However, my previous short answer is correct **irrespective** of that.  (That's why I said "short answer"!)

Comment: @StephenC can you elaborate on how array types are not typically created dynamically, according to "The classes "[I", "[C", et al, are "pre-defined" in the JVM -- there are no .class files corresponding to them. Java also will implicitly create, on the fly" [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10674614/11306652)

Comment: Edit your question, and I / we will consider whether it is sufficiently distinct from the dup to be reopened.

Comment: But also, bear in the mind that some people who answer Questions are inclined to be a bit "loose" with their use of the terminology.

Comment: @StephenC i tried my best to edit

Comment: 1. Yes. Both the JLS and the JVM Spec state clearly that a class object for an array is dynamically created. [JLS #10.8 'Class Objects for Arrays'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.8) and [JVM Spec #5.3.3 'Creating Array Classes'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se12/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3.3). And JLS #10.8 states clearly that 'the direct superclass of every array type is Object.' 2. You can get the `Class` object via the `.getClass()` method on the array instance, as for any other object.

Comment: @user207321 i understand that a Class object is dynamically created, but i was wondering if there was a dynamically created "array class" with a dynamically created Class object

Comment: @user207421 so the dynamically created Class object defines the array object? sorry im a student, im trying my best but i have no idea whats going on

Comment: No, `int[] array = new int[10]` defines the object; `array.getClass()` gives you the `Class`.

Comment: @user207421 which returns "[I" which is what? the array's class that is dynamically created by jvm?

Comment: That is the name of the dynamically created array class, as given by `array.getClass().getName()` or `array.getClass().toString()` in the above. [If you `print()` the class it automatically calls `toString()`.]

Comment: @user207421 oh thats what ive been wondering the whole time.. when arrays are created, the JVM dynamically creates an "array class" (with Object as a superclass) that defines the array object? Additionally there is a Class object associated with the dynamically created "array class".

Comment: That is correct. NB The answer that was described above as 'not appropriate' is indeed appropriate, and the reason advanced above is nonsense, as is 'an array is not an object of any class'.

Comment: @another-dave Please don't post BS here. It just causes pointless confusion. Everything you've stated here is directly contradicted by the JLS and JVM Spec.

Comment: There are statements in the JLS and the JVM spec saying that an array type is not a class type.

Comment: JLS 8, section 10.8.  JVM 8, section 2.4.  I grant you that wording in JVM section 5.3.3 contradicts what is says in 2.4.