# How can an object reference in java hold the reference to a primitive double dimensional int array

Tags: java, arrays, object, oop

I have a piece of code-

```
public class Sudoku {
    static int[][] game;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [][] games= new int[3][3];
        Object obj =games;
    }

}
```

My question here is how can the "games" reference variable be assigned to the reference variable of type "Object"? I thought the "**ClassCastException**" would be thrown at runtime. But the code compiles and runs fine.
Isnt the reference variable "games" incompatible to be assigned to an Object reference because of 2 reasons-
1)"games" is the reference to a double dimensional int array, whereas "obj" is the reference to an Object.
2)int is clearly a primitive variable..how can it be assigned to a variable of type object?
I am running this in the Intellij IDE.

Comment: All arrays are instances of `Object`. Any kind of object can be assigned to an `Object` reference.

Comment: "int is clearly a primitive variable" yes, but this isn't an `int`, it's an `int[][]`, which is a reference type. But you can write `Object obj = 0;` anyway, because of autoboxing.

Comment: Similar to question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267790/how-are-arrays-implemented-in-java

Comment: Think of it in a way - anything that needs `new` for creating an instance is an `Object`

Comment: Understood, when ever new is Used that means I am working on an Object and "int[][], which is a reference type." thanks guys! I had mentioned to mention the reason for downvoting if some body plans on doing that but still somebody down voted without mentioning any reason. Anyways thanks @AndyTurner and Vasily

Answer (score 1):

> Isnt the reference variable "games" incompatible to be assigned to an Object reference because of 2 reasons- 1)"games" is the reference to a double dimensional int array, whereas "obj" is the reference to an Object. 2)int is clearly a primitive variable

You are correct that `int` is a primitive type. However, the type of `games` in your example is `int[][]`, not `int`, and is a subclass of `Object`.

Answer (score -1):

if your code were

```
int [] games= new int[3]; 
Object obj =games; // will fail to compile,
```

but declare `game` as `int [][] games` can be assigned to `obj`.

Comment: It will not fail to compile. Answer is incorrect. And no explanation is provided.

Comment: Sorry, the code will not fail to compile,

Arrays are objects as well, and since "obj" is declared as an Object then the code will compile without issues.

You could declare Arrays of primitive, string, or anything else, they are considered as Object.